# Is it possible to open up File Explorer and click on a text file to obtain the address name in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, text-files

I am trying to write code in VBA that automatically opens up File Explorer so that you can then navigate to a text file and click on it to obtain the address of that file. Then the file explorer closes and the address is saved into a variable. Unfortunately I am very new to VBA and only could figure out how to open up the file explorer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    Dim Foldername As String
    Foldername = "\\server\Instructions\"

    Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & Foldername & "", vbNormalFocus
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your Workbook module.  It opens the Explorer dialog box, lets the user pick a file, then prints the path:

```
Sub get_path()
Dim folderChosenPath As String
Dim inputFileDialog As FileDialog
Set inputFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With inputFileDialog
    .Title = "Select a File."
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    folderChosenPath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Debug.Print folderChosenPath
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:
SOURCE : INTERNET
Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String)

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\"

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder
'enter code here'
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File

```
Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

'--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured

r = 14
For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
    Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13
    Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name
    Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
    Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size
    Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type
    Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified
    Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" &amp; FileItem.Path &amp; """,""" &amp; "Click Here to Open" &amp; """)"

    r = r + 1   ' next row number
Next FileItem

Set FileItem = Nothing
Set SourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

End Sub